# Zooming out from content of UIscrollview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I used to use these two lines to zoom out on the content of my scrollview. However since iOS8, I can't zoom out anymore. It does nothing.

Can someone explain to me why. I have autolayout turned off.

```
  [scrollView setZoomScale:0.3 animated:YES];
  scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(tempSize.width*0.3, tempSize.height*0.3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this will help you, but this method works for me when zooming in iOS 8. In this code, an imageView is in the scroll view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0;
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.PhotoView.frame.size;
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
}


- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
return self.PhotoView;
}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView*)view atScale:(CGFloat)scale{
}
```

Comment: yes it did! I forgot to put the delegate methods ! Thank you!!